# Unable to get git-receive-pack to work with golang ssh tunneling

Tags: git, sockets, go, ssh, ssh-tunnel

i'm trying to forward git commands via a Golang SSH reverse proxy.
Both commands, "git-upload-pack" and "git-receive-pack" works. Problem is "git-receive-pack" send a error after files transmission.

Here's a screenshot of the error:
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p76UF.png)

I've also tried to do it with github.com public repository, same result.

Nearly sure the problem is in those two functions, but after researches I couldn't find the solution.
If anyone has any idea of ​​the cause or even a solution, I'll be pleased to read you.

*Function to connect SSH server to Git server:*

```
func connectToDestination(user, host string) (*ssh.Client, *ssh.Session, error) {
sshConfig := &ssh.ClientConfig{
    User:            user,
    HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(),
    Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
        PublicKeyFile("./keys/host_key"),
    },
}
client, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", host, sshConfig)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("dial return with", err)
    return nil, nil, err
}
session, err := client.NewSession()
if err != nil {
    client.Close()
    return nil, session, err
}
return nil, session, nil}
```

*Function to handle execution when a client connect to SSH server:*

```
func handleExec(ch ssh.Channel, req *ssh.Request) {
command := string(req.Payload[4:])
fmt.Println(command)
gitCmds := []string{"git-receive-pack", "git-upload-pack"}

valid := false
for _, cmd := range gitCmds {
    if strings.HasPrefix(command, cmd) {
        valid = true
    }
}
if !valid {
    ch.Write([]byte("command is not a GIT command\r\n"))
    ch.Close()
    return
}

////////////////////CODE HERE///////////////////////
// _, targetSession, err := connectToDestination("git", "localhost:2220")
// _, targetSession, err := connectToDestination("git", "github.com:22")
_, targetSession, err := connectToDestination("git", "172.18.0.3:22")

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}

targetStderr, _ := targetSession.StderrPipe()
targetStdout, _ := targetSession.StdoutPipe()
targetStdin, _ := targetSession.StdinPipe()
wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
wg.Add(3)

go func() {
    defer wg.Done()
    io.Copy(targetStdin, ch)
}()
go func() {
    defer wg.Done()
    io.Copy(ch.Stderr(), targetStderr)
}()
go func() {
    defer wg.Done()
    io.Copy(ch, targetStdout)
}()

targetSession.Run(string(req.Payload[4:]))
wg.Wait()

targetSession.Close()
ch.Close()}
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Really struggled with this problem a few years back trying to route ssh on SDN. Ended up giving up. But still very interested in the answer